# How to find my network and database access

Tags: windows, security, active-directory, sql-server

Our company gets audited pretty regularly and I was wondering if there's an easy way to find out which accounts have access to what on our network?

We're an all windows development shop, so all our servers are Win 2003-2008 and our databases are all Sql server 05/08. Is there any software I can run that will show for each entity (ie: Windows server or SQL database), which AD accounts/groups have what type of access?

Thanks!
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

you can run this script against all registered servers in SSMS:

```
SELECT loginname AS NAME, dbname, denylogin, hasaccess, 
sysadmin, securityadmin, setupadmin, processadmin, diskadmin, 
dbcreator, bulkadmin 
FROM sys.syslogins
```

Does a pretty decent job. I used this for a Ernst & Young security audit at our shop.